# Symmetrical Digits: which can be written by single Numeral like 22, 3333,66666,7777

Tags: number-theory

as we can see that all SD of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 up to any place will be composite.we can prove it. But, how to prove that all SD of 1( except 11) will be composite?
Like 111(37×3),1111(101×11),11111(41×271),    111111(37037×3) e.t.c
this is seem an conjecture to me? i believe all SD of 1(except 11) will be composite?
can anyone tell me an SD of 1, which is Prime?

for more illustration see " The Number Theory of Aryabhatta"  at http://themathematics.in

Comment: The case of $n\cdots n = \frac{1}{9}(10^n - 1)$ with $n > 1$ is trivial, and see http://oeis.org/A004023 for the case $n = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{10^{19}-1}{9} = 1111111111111111111  $$

is prime

$$ \frac{10^{23}-1}{9} = 11111111111111111111111  $$

is also prime

Answer (score 1):

If the digit is not $1$, it is obvious that the only primes of the desired form are $2,3,5,7$. For the rep-unit case, $\frac{10^k-1}{9}$ has been proven to be prime for $$k=2, 19, 23, 317, 1031$$ and is probable prime for $$k=49081,86453,109297,270343$$ See here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit#Decimal_repunit_primes

It is conjectured (but a proof and also a disproof is almost surely out of reach) that infinite many rep-unit primes exist. Also note that $\frac{10^k-1}{9}$ can only be prime, if $k$ is prime.